# typeinfo pragma visibility error

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, cmake, g++

I'm trying to use shared_ptr from std:: in c++ 11 so I'm including  which apparently uses typeinfo. The problem is that I'm getting the error bellow.

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/memory:71:0,
                 from /home/dev/openclTest/modules/Quant.cpp:10:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/typeinfo:39:37: error: expected ‘}’ before end of line
 #pragma GCC visibility push(default)
```

From what it sounds like, this is a known bug listed here:
 https://lists.debian.org/debian-gcc/2007/09/msg00497.html

Anyway, I was hoping I didn't have to use boosts library, so if there's a quick fix anyone knows about, please let me know. I'm using cmake and g++ to build the project.

Thanks!

Comment: This bug is for GCC 4.2 so I don't really think it is still relevant for your version (4.8). Post the code you are actually trying to compile (Quant.cpp). For `std::shard_ptr` you only need to include [`<memory>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar issue with GCC 4.9.2. It seems to be the common error message in case you forget some braces in a file included prior to typeinfo.

I did not find the code to exactly reproduce the message but got something very similar using this minimal test:

```
test.cpp:

{
#include <typeinfo>

int main() {}
```

I guess it is likely the same error as yours as it happens in very different GCC versions. In case it really is the same issue, check your other includes.